# No option for importing Java project from existing Ant build file in Eclipse Indigo

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I am trying to import a Java project with an Ant build file into Eclipse, but am unable to find the option to do so.

I looked under:
`File -> New Project -> Java`

but the only option there is `Java Project`

How do I get the functionality for importing from an Ant build file?

I am using **Eclipse Indigo** on Ubuntu 12.04

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to select `Project` and not `Java Project` under `New` menu item, this will pop up `New Project` wizard dialog with more options. Try:

> File->New->Project->Java->Java project from existing Ant Buildfile.

Comment: I tried this multiple times and it doesn't seem to work. Under the "Java" category of New Project wizard, there is only: "Java Project"

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're in the Java perspective. Then click on `File >> New >> Project >> Java Project from Existing Ant Buildfile`

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't seem to show up either. There is only "Java Project" on there.